# "for a delay without delay" means?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The investigation revealed that Cherish had cancer. Doctors told Lewis that germ cell cancer is growing in Cherish's ovary. But it was surprising that germ cell cancer in girls' ovaries is not the same at this age. Doctors started treatment **for a delay without delay**. Cherish's chemotherapy also began with treatment. Because of which all his hair blown away Let the doctors now have removed the tumor from the stomach's stomach. Because of which the size of his stomach is gradually becoming normal.

What does that bold sentence mean?

**"for a delay without delay"**

Does that mean "*delaying the death* by starting the treatment without delay"?

Comment: Note this writing sample is not a great example. It is confusing on several points. "cancer in girls' ovaries is not the same" Not the same as what? "all his hair blown away" Presumably Cherish is a girl as we are told she has ovaries, so who is the male whose hair is blown away? And what does the writer mean by "blown away"? Did chemotherapy cause someone's hair to fall out? "Blown away" is a poor choice of words to express that idea. "Let the doctors now have removed ..." is grammatically incorrect. Etc.

Comment: @Jay You are right. There are so many errors in that article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to look at the entire sentence to get to the meaning.

> Doctors started treatment for a delay without delay.

If we take the first part of this sentence, *Doctors started treatment for a delay*, we can conclude that doctors started a treatment that will delay the development of the cancer.

The second part, *without delay*, means the started it immediately, without delaying.

To make the sentence clearer, we can rewrite it like this:

> The doctors immediately started a treatment to slow the growth of the cancer down.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer. I misinterpreted that as "delay the death" instead of "delay the development of the cancer".